# In navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() method getting error the permission was revoked

Tags: angular, geolocation

if (navigator.geolocation) {

```
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    console.log(position);
    this.isLocationEnabled = true;
    this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  });
}
```

the issue comes when from browser if I disable the location access and then enable the location access so in second although the acess is given I'm getting this error

any solution for this

if location access is given it should return the position. but once if i disable by mistake in browser and then enable location it give me the permission was revoked

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap this call with a permission check

```
navigator.permissions.query({ name: "geolocation" }).then((result) => {
  if (result.state === "granted") {
    // OK 
  } else if (result.state === "prompt") {
    
  } else {
  // denied
});
```

Comment: after wrapping also I'm getting same error GeolocationPositionError {code: 1, message: 'The permission was revoked'} seems like if by mistake user deined the location acess then no way to get the position even after that we give the permission the method throws this error

Comment: name: 'geolocation', state: 'granted', onchange: null   state is granted after that also the method gives error revoked pls help

Comment: I had the same issue on dev. It's cause of insecure origins. When I clear everything and reopen the tab everything worked